# pandas series.sum() how to skip some indexes

Tags: python, pandas

My data is :

```
ipdb> self.valid_secpos[self.valid_secpos>0]
000793.SZ     4500
000895.SZ     2800
601601.SH     2000
601618.SH    12200
002024.SZ     5200
000960.SZ     3000
600030.SH     2100
... ...
Length: 139, dtype: int64

ipdb> self.valid_secpos_price[self.valid_secpos_price>0]
000793.SZ    15.732091
000895.SZ    23.986040
601601.SH    33.867075
601618.SH     5.567947
002024.SZ    13.205894
000960.SZ    22.500000
600030.SH    33.511157
... ...
Length: 139, dtype: float64
```

And I want to get the sum of `res = self.valid_secpos[self.valid_secpos>0] * self.valid_secpos_price[self.valid_secpos_price>0]`, that is `res.sum()`. But, I don't need to add the value of these indexes `s = set([u'000826.SZ', u'600832.SH', u'600597.SH', ...])`. So, My code is:

```
sum = 0
for _id, _val in zip(res.index, res.values):
    if _id not in s:
        sum += _val
```

It works, but, how to use pandas built-in functions to do this. The for loop is really nasty. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the criteria `valid_secpos>0` and `valid_secpos_price>0` are compatible?  What if there is a datapoint that satisfies one but not the other?  Better to define a single criterion and do `(self.valid_secpos[criterion]*self.valid_secpos_price[criterion]).sum()`.

Comment: @BrenBarn, they are compatible. I am sure. `self.valid_secpos[self.valid_secpos>0]` it means to get all the values in`self.valid_secpos` that `>0`. They are from my ipdb console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better get rid of the rows you don't want, then you don't need to skip anything.

```
res.drop(s).sum()
```